# What are some ways to improve this long mysql search query?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Looking to improve this mysql select statement for a search query:

```
Select * from table WHERE ( user = '$search_query'
OR user LIKE '$search_query %'
OR keyword LIKE '$search_query'
OR tag LIKE '$search_query'
OR tag LIKE '% $search_query'
OR tag LIKE '% $search_query%'
OR tag LIKE '$search_query%'
OR REPLACE(question, ',' ,'') LIKE '$search_query %'
OR REPLACE(question, ',' ,'') LIKE '% $search_query'
OR REPLACE(question, ',' ,'') LIKE '% $search_query %' 
OR REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE(question, '\'', ''), ',', ''), '.',''), ':',''), ';',''), '!',''), '?','') LIKE '%$search_query%'
)
```

The reason it's broke down the way it is, is because say if someone searches for "art", I don't want it showing results for "heart" as well.

I really need to have of these same functions but running fewer resources.

Comment: Have you tried FULLTEXT indexes?

Comment: can you explayn the reason why you make three different cases for `$search_query %`, `% $search_query`, and `% $search_query %`?

Comment: It's explained above, for instance if I search "art" and just use '%$search_query%' then it will return every instance of "art" such as "heart attack" and I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your table is `MyISAM`, you can create a `FULLTEXT` index on it:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX fx_mytable_user_tag_question ON mytable (user, tag, question)

SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   MATCH(user, tag, question) AGAINST ('+some*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This query will return `some` and `something` but not `awesome`.

Actually, the first step (creating the index) is not required, however, it will speed up the queries and allow more complex searches (not limited to `BOOLEAN MODE`) and relevance ranging.

By default, minimal length of a search query is `4` characters, so `art` mentioned in your example would not be found.

To work around this, you will have to change parameter `ft_min_word_len` in server settings.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like

```
OR tag LIKE '$search_query'
OR tag LIKE '$search_query%'
```

would return identical results to only running

```
OR tag LIKE '$search_query%'
```

Same with

```
OR tag LIKE '% $search_query'
OR tag LIKE '% $search_query%'
```

---

Searching around for this question, I learned that MySQL supports [regular expression searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html). Using these, if you are able to specify what pattern the `%` should match. This would help with all those pesky spaces, because you could just use `\s?`.

Comment: `LIKE '% heart %'` will not match `heart attack`.

Comment: @Quassnoi: not that, but `'% $search_query%'` matches `artwiz`.

Comment: @black: `SELECT REPLACE('artwiz', ',', '') LIKE '% art %'` returns `0` to me.

Comment: @Quassnoi: I'm talking about `OR tag LIKE '$search_query%'`.

Comment: @black: and I'm talking about the `question` part.

Answer (score 0):

Restructure your database such that tags are stored in a separate table, with one row for each tag on a question, so that you can run a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM question
WHERE question_id IN (
  SELECT question_id FROM question_tags WHERE tag = '$search_query'
) OR <...>
```

Depending on how you want search keywords to work, you may be able to use a similar solution there.